# manim execute but nothing happen

Tags: python, pycairo, manim

I installed manim community edition with all the requirements necessary (latex, numpy, pycairo, pydub ...).
at the last, i faced this problem:
when i run this commande `python3.8 -m manim example_scenes.py SquareToCircle -pl`. the terminal stuck and i get nothing.

I'm using python 3.8 en ubuntu 20.04

remarque: the same thing happen when i use jupiter notebook

Thanks

[image]

Comment: There are two versions of manim, one from ManimCommunity, one from 3b1b.  Which is this?  The SquareToCircle sample is in the community edition, but it's not part of example_scenes.py.  You  need to type the example from their GitHub page.

Comment: I'm using the community edition

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the command line in your screenshot (which is correct) was different from the command in your description (which is not).  Double-check that you typed example.py exactly like their sample.  The command takes 15 or 20 seconds to run, but it produces an mp4 file in a subdirectory.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but when i try to install manim with pycharm in venv mode the issue fixed